# What are the advantages using SUMO vector for expression?

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-expression, transformation, experimental, vector

My question is : What are the advantages using SUMO vector for expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [pET SUMO info page](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/K30001) states

> It utilizes a small ubiquitin-related modifier (SUMO) fusion,
>   belonging to the growing family of ubiquitin-related proteins, to
>   enhance the solubility of expressed fusion proteins.

So, in general, you could consider using SUMO vectors to improve the solubility of your protein.